# The limit of the remainder in Maclaurin expansions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, power-series, taylor-expansion

Consider smooth functions $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f^{(n+1)}$ exists.

Then, we have for some $\theta_n \in (0,1)$

$f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k + \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\theta_n x)}{(n+1)!} x^{n+1}$

Define $R_{n+1}(x) := \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\theta_n x)}{(n+1)!} x^{n+1} = f(x) - \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$

Now consider the Maclaurin series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^n.$

If $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} R_{n+1}(x) = 0,$ then the Maclaurin series converges $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ and if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} R_{n+1}(x)$ diverges at $x_0 \in \mathbb R$, then the Maclaurin series diverges at $x_0$ except for when $x_0 = 0$ where it trivially converges to $f(0).$

Now, we could also have both of these two different situations on different intervals. For example, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ converges whenever $|x| < 1$, because $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} R_{n+1}(x) = \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x) - \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k = \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x} = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ whenever } |x| < 1 \\ + \infty \text{ whenever } x \geq 1 \\ \text{undefined whenever } x \leq 1 \end{cases}$

Is there any smooth function $f$ such that $\exists \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} R_{n+1}(x) \neq 0$ for $\forall x \in I \subseteq \mathbb R$? Or framed in an other way: is it possible for the Maclaurin series to converge  $\forall x \in I \subseteq \mathbb R$ (either uniformly or pointwise), but not towards $f(x)$?

Comment: I don't agree with this "if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} R_{n+1}(x)$diverges, then the Maclaurin series diverges everywhere except for $x=0$
" !

Comment: @Ashkan Should have added "$\forall x$".

EDIT: Or really, if it diverges for some $x_0$, then the series will diverge at $x = x_0$ too.

Comment: Did you this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function